# How do you protect your commercial HTML/CSS and JavaScript codes on their demos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What are the fundamentals to protect the source codes of commercial HTML/CSS and JavaScript files on their demos in a market?

Come on, please don't mark this question as off-topic as I know I can try to:

- Disable the right click.
- Disable the *[Ctrl + Shift + i]*.
- Disable the *[Ctrl + u]*.
- Learn and use a JavaScript obfuscator.

I want to know **all the fundamentals** to protect my commercial codes as we all need to know.

Is an obfuscator enough for JScript? **How about for CSS3 animations and effects?**

Any right way to do this? Is there a standard open source or any other tricks for this?

Comment: - And also to use `<iframe>`.

Comment: Have you ever known a program that cant be find on the pirate bay? If they need it they will hack it. no matter what you do there is always a revese method. your best options is to add a legal advice.

Comment: Anything that is accessible via a webpage is copyable...so your HTML,CSS and JS are all available to anyone who can use Developer Tools

Comment: make a video of the working site?

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscating your JS/CSS will be your best bet. If the demo has to work, then those files have to be downloaded to the client's machine.

From then onward, your files are in possession of the client and you can't but just obfuscate those to give the client a hard time to figure your code out.

How can you disable <kbd>F12</kbd> which launches Developer Console? And what about <kbd>Context Menu</kbd> key on the keyboard, which can be easily used to circumvent the disabled right click?

If you want fail-proof method, then just don't have a demo at all or have limited options available in it.

Comment: I'm familiar with *[F12]* Developer Tools, I just didn't know if it's possible to disable. Thanks for spending time answering.. Did you know the most used obfuscator at this time?